# Call server side form validation from JQuery

Tags: java, jquery, spring

I have a Thymeleaf/Spring form mapped to DTO object with @NotNull, @Size, @NotEmpty annotations. After submit I check if there are any errors, and return to the form page or save the form - pretty standard approach. Is there a way to call validation only from JQuery? What I mean is: if the from is not valid - return false or redirect to form page, but if it's OK, return true and stop right there, do not submit.

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/form}" th:object="${businessTripDTO}" th:method="post" id="myForm">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="idNum">Destination: </label>
        <input id="idNum" type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{destination}" />
        <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('destination')}" th:errors="*{destination}" class="has-error"></label>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String sendTripForm(@Valid BusinessTripDTO businessTripDTO, BindingResult bindingResult){

if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "form";
}
...
```

JQuery from form.html that calls submit, but should call server-side validation only.

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.odom-submit', function (e) {
        $('#myForm').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: You can surely implement client-side validation in order to avoid useless requests, but bean validation would have nothing to do with it, you would have to duplicate the needed validation

Comment: Client-side validation is not an option unfortunately

Comment: You can catch the submit event, make a `$.ajax` call to a server side validation function and based on the response from that call either let the submit continue or suppress it.